# nested list item when another element is hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a nested list in my menu and I wanted the first child of the sub list highlighted when the parent is highlighted. I want to code this just by using CSS (in SCSS file format) This is a list within a list. I have list items below another list item of another

```html
<ul id="sub-list">                                               
      <li class="sub-list-item">                                                                 
        <a href="#"><span>창업교육</span></a>   <!--serves as the parent when this is highlighted, the first child is also highlighted.-->                                                                   
          <ul class="sub-sub-list"> <!--sublist-->                                                                       
            <li class="item"><a href="#" class="sub-sub-title">창업정규교과</a></li>                                                                           
            <li class="item"><a href="#" class="sub-sub-title">창업비정규교과</a></li> 
          </ul>
      </li> 
      <li class="sub-list-item">
         <span>this is another list item in class="sub-list"</span>
      </li>                                                  
    </ul>
```

*EDIT: changed some of the words being used in this question to make this one understandable. and added another child item to .sub-list to make a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is the "parent" (by class or id ) and what is the exact element type (by class or id ) that should be highlighted?

Comment: when .sub-list-item > span is highligted, the first child of the sublist will be highlighted. @cantuket

Comment: Ok well in that case I misunderstood. @soulshined  has the answer you're looking for. Note, the `<span>` element is in an entirely different branch of the DOM than the `.item`s so it would be impossible to do that without JS. You need to target the `<a>` element instead

Answer (score 0):

The 'span' (`<a>`) isn't actually a parent. It's a sibling. The parent to the first child (list item) in the sub list is the `<ul class="sub-sub-list">`. That means they are siblings.

You can use the `+` selector to target siblings: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
.sub-list-item a:hover + ul > li:first-child {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<ul id="sub-list">
  <li class="sub-list-item">
    <a href="#"><span>창업교육</span></a>
    <!--serves as the parent when this is highlighted, the first child is also highlighted.-->
    <ul class="sub-sub-list">
      <!--sublist-->
      <li class="item"><a href="#" class="sub-sub-title">창업정규교과</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#" class="sub-sub-title">창업비정규교과</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi! is the '+' selector allowed in sass? just wanna ask. this is my first time coding in sass. @soulshined

Comment: SASS is CSS, they are the same. It's no problem @AlexDeneris . You can write CSS/SASS in a SASS file. O